# Cant install OpenAL on Linux

Tags: linux, centos7, rhel, openal, love2d

Im trying to install LÖVE2D v0.10.2 on my CentOS7 VM. But when I run    ./configure
and it just sais "configure: error: LÖVE needs "OpenAL", please install "OpenAL" with development files and try again". I look with    yum search openal
for something to install, but there are a no found match, anthough there should be one.

How can I get rid of that error?

Comment: Have you searched for `yum search openal-dev` and `yum search libopenal-dev`?

Comment: Yes. The thing is, that you dont have to write the words out. So 'open' or evel 'al' should work (I tried it with different combinations of Capital and small Letters), but there is just nothing

Comment: There is no OpenAL for the Fedora 18 .. 20 based CentOS 7. Fedora 19 has `openal-soft, openal-soft-devel` http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/19/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/o/